# Cmake does not work with openMP on Maverick

Tags: c++, cmake, openmp, osx-mavericks

I am using OpenMP to write parallel code.
Here is a section from the CMakeLists used in my case.

```
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenMP REQUIRED)
    if(OPENMP_FOUND)
    message("OPENMP FOUND")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
    endif()
```

But, when we start cmake .., It seems that it deos not find OpenMP package and I get this error

```
Try OpenMP C flag = [ ]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [/openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-Qopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-xopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [+Oopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-qsmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-mp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [ ]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [/openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-Qopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-xopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [+Oopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-qsmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-mp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
CMake Error at /opt/local/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)
```

Here is CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

#Declaration du projet

project(MYfirstcamke)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

#Inclusion de opencv

include_directories(/usr/local/include/)

link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenMP REQUIRED)
if(OPENMP_FOUND)
message("OPENMP FOUND")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")
endif()

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

file(

    GLOB_RECURSE

    source_files

    src/*


)
#declaration de l'executable

add_executable(

my_executable

${source_files}

)
#Configuration de l'edition de lien.
target_link_libraries(

my_executable opencv_core  opencv_imgproc opencv_video opencv_highgui ${PCL_LIBRARIES}


)
```

How can I fix that? I am sure that openMPi is installed and it located on opt/local/include

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mixing up between OpenMP and OpenMPI? I see that you used both tags, and that you refer to OpenMPI at the end of the post. But both are completely different. OpenMP is a standard of multi-threaded parallel language extension, and OpenMPI is an implementation of the MPI standard for message passing. Which of the two are you after?

Comment: OpenMP is not a package, but an integral part of the compiler. Xcode used to provide an OpenMP-enabled GCC a long time ago. Then Apple switched to Clang, which doesn't have OpenMP support, at least not in the versions shipped with Xcode. You should install GCC either from source or using Homebrew/MacPorts/whatever.

Comment: @Gilles, May be I am mixing between OpenMP and OpenMPI. I thought that OpenMP was deprecated and become OpenMP.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I have installed GCC but How can I specify the compiler in CMakeLists.txt. I have added the CMakeLists.txt file in my question.

Comment: I don't understand CMake, but probably something like `export CC=gcc-4.9; export CXX=g++-4.9` before running CMake should suffice. Replace `gxx-4.9` with the actual name of the corresponding compiler.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP and MPI are two entirely different things.

OMP requires compiler support, which on OS X you'll need via [Homebrew](http://homebrew). (you can also install MPI via Homebrew too, which is nice).

```
brew install clang-omp
```

After you've installed clang-omp, you can then tell CMake to use that compiler by invoking it like so.

```
CC=clang-omp CXX=clang-omp++ cmake <insert your normal cmake parameters here>
```

Comment: According to http://openmp.llvm.org/, 
> "With the release of Clang 3.8.0, OpenMP 3.1 support is enabled in Clang by default, and the OpenMP runtime is therefore built as a normal part of the Clang build"

I just could not understand why I still have to install "clang-omp", could you kindly explain why?

Another problem is that the `clang-omp` formula asks for different version of clang (and `compiler-rt` etc.) from the `llvm` formula, so what should I do to make things right?

Comment: I am trying with CMake 3.7 and clang 4.0 and my `find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)` fails.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you can also install gcc-5/g++-5 from homebrew. The plain vanilla gcc-5 installation (without Clang wrappers) will support OpenMP and this should get detected by CMake through Find_Package.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to install and use GNU GCC. Assuming you have it installed or will install it via HomeBrew `brew install gcc`:

```
if(APPLE)
  set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/gcc-9")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/g++-9")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "/usr/local/bin/gfortran")
endif()
```

the `-9` version might change at the time.